# Alias an URL in Apache in order to route requests on a certain URL through a PHP-script

Tags: php, apache, alias

I am using Apache 2.2.6 with suPHP 0.6.2 and PHP 5.2.6 and I am trying to use an Alias in order to route all requests on a certain URL trough a PHP script. I want all requests to /test to go through index.php. In the Apache virtualhost config I have set up an Alias `Alias /test /index.php`. index.php is just a dummy script containing the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Requesting http://localhost/index.php works and gives the expected output, however requesting http://localhost/test does not and gives me a 403 error, the error.log contains the following:

```
[Wed Jan 27 17:13:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /index.php
```

What is wrong with my Alias?

**Edit:**
I almost forgot to mention that rewriting /test to /index.php through mod_rewrite works as well, however I want to avoid mod_rewrite on my production server if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alias requires an absolute path, so `Alias /test /var/www/index.php` made it work.